# Div not to display if no results found -

Tags: php

I have an area on my page of coloured swatches (and the tile AVAIALBLE COLOURS) that i only want to display if there is a result for them in the database.

here is my code:

```
private function getWTVariationHighlights($productId, $variationId)
{
    $output_str = "";
    $output_str .="<div class=\"mainProductSwatchesTitle\"><b>AVAILABLE COLOURS</b>\n";
    $output_str .= "<div class=\"mainProductSwatches\">\n";
    $sql = "select voptionid, vovalue from [|PREFIX|]product_variation_options where vovariationid=$variationId and (voname='Colour' or voname='Color')";
    $result = $this->db->Query($sql);
    while ($row = $this->db->fetch($result)) {
        $sql = "select * from [|PREFIX|]variation_option_highlight where variation_option_id=" . $row['voptionid'] . " and product_id=" . $productId;
        $result2 = $this->db->Query($sql);
        if($row2 = $this->db->fetch($result2)){
            if($row2['thumb_location']){
                $output_str .= "<a href=\"#\" onmouseover=\"changeMain('" . $row2['location'] . "')\"><img src=\"" 
                    . $GLOBALS['ShopPath'] . "/product_images/hfh_highlight_images/" . $row2['thumb_location'] . "\" /></a>\n";
            }
        }
    }
    $output_str .= "</div>\n";
    $output_str .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
    $output_str .= "function changeMain(src)\n";
    $output_str .= "{\n";
        $output_str .= "document.getElementById('phthumb').src = '" . $GLOBALS['ShopPath'] . "/product_images/hfh_highlight_images/' + src;\n";
    $output_str .= "}\n";
    $output_str .= "</script>\n";

    return $output_str;
}
```

Comment: SO ist mainly a website for concrete technical questions. You don't even ask one. Please see, if you can provide some more info on what exactly is the problem. What have you already tried? etc.

Answer (score 1):

simple use css

```
div:empty
{display:none;}
```